# Why have same interrupt for all system calls?

Tags: linux, system-calls, interrupt

What is the reason that have same interrupt (int 0X80) for all system calls  ?

Comment: Why not? A answer can be, that the length of the irq vector table (was) quite limited. But what should it help to use more interrupts? I can't see a reason to use more interrupts... It will not speed up anything nor did it simplify anything nor...

Comment: You can't pick interrupt vectors based on variables. It has to be hard-coded. By using a single vector and putting the requested function in a register, it is far more dynamic. It also makes the mechanism similar across systems, some of which do not have large interrupt tables. Finally, there are too many system calls to fit in the IVT.